# JaxbAccessorF_value cannot be cast to... in invoking getDocumentRepositoryPortSoap12 method of a ihe.iti.xds_b._2007.DocumentRepositoryService object

Tags: java, maven, service

I am modifying/correcting code for our implementation of the `xd-common` java code available from `repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nhind/xd-common/`

When invoking the following...

`proxy = service.getDocumentRepositoryPortSoap12(new MTOMFeature(true, 1));`

... the log shows

> "axbAccessorF_value cannot be cast to
>   com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor"

I've looked at several places for a solution.  Many suggest the issue could be with a duplicate JAXB lib on the classpath and, in some cases, request the Maven dependency tree to address this.  I have included the maven dependency tree; but, I don't know how to tell anything about duplicate classpaths from this.

The error occurs in the `DocumentRepositoryProxy` class of `org.nhindirect.xd.proxy`.

```
private void initProxy()
{
    try
    {
         URL url = DocumentRepositoryProxy.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
                "XDS.b_DocumentRepositoryWSDLSynchMTOM.wsdl");

        LOGGER.info("url: " + url.toString());

        QName qname = new QName("urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007", "DocumentRepository_Service");
        DocumentRepositoryService service = new DocumentRepositoryService(url, qname);

        if (handlerResolver != null)
            service.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);

        LOGGER.info("Before getDocumentRepositoryPortSoap12");
        proxy = service.getDocumentRepositoryPortSoap12(new MTOMFeature(true, 1));
        LOGGER.info("After getDocumentRepositoryPortSoap12");

        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) proxy;
        SOAPBinding binding = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
        binding.setMTOMEnabled(true);

        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error initializing proxy.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: ERROR 15:09:31,027 | org.nhindirect.xd.proxy.DocumentRepositoryProxy | Error initializing proxy.
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: java.lang.ClassCastException: oasis.names.tc.ebxml_regrep.xsd.rs._3.RegistryError$JaxbAccessorF_value cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextFactory.newContext(JAXBRIContextFactory.java:90)

Comment: The last "Caused by" tag in the log begins with "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oasis.names.tc.ebxml_regrep.xsd.rs._3.RegistryError$JaxbAccessorF_value cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor"

Comment: I also have the Maven dependency tree; but, I don' know how to post it within the character limits.